# Add vertical line between the vertical divs

Tags: html, css

I want to add a vertical line between the multiple divs so that it looks like the attached image:

[image]
I'm trying to achieve that by adding a div .border and setting its position absolute. However I want to add some margin between the border and make the border appear behind the boxes as in above image.

Here's the code I'm trying:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="wrap">

<div class="box">
    <div class="border"></div>
    <div class="figure"></div>  
    <div class="right"> right</div>    
</div>

<div class="box">
    <div class="border"></div>
    <div class="figure"></div>  
    <div class="right"> right</div>
</div>

<div class="box">
     <div class="border"></div>
    <div class="figure"></div>  
    <div class="right"> right</div>
</div>

</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.wrap{
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.box{
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-top: 50px;   
}

.box:first-child{
    margin-top: 0;
}

.figure{
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background: yellow;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 10px;
}

.right{
    display: inline-block;
}

.border{
  border-right: 3px solid red;
  height: 100%;
  left: 24px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 1px;
}

.box:last-child .border{
    display: none;
}
```

**JSFiddle:**

http://jsfiddle.net/w5TY9/

Comment: ... and what's the reason for -1?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you go.

**[WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/w5TY9/4/)**

**The HTML:**

```
<div class="wrap">

<div class="box">
    <div class="border"></div>
    <div class="figure"></div>  
    <div class="right"> </div>    
</div>

<div class="box">
    <div class="border"></div>
    <div class="figure"></div>  
    <div class="right"> </div>
</div>

<div class="box">
     <div class="border"></div>
    <div class="figure"></div>  
    <div class="right"> </div>
</div>

</div>
```

**The CSS:**

```
.wrap{
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.box{
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-top: 50px;   
}

.box:first-child{
    margin-top: 0;
}

.figure{
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background: yellow;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 10px;
}

.right{
    display: inline-block;
}

.border {
    border-right: 3px solid #FF0000;
    height: 98%;
    left: 24px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 1px;
    z-index: -1;
}

.box:last-child .border{
    display: none;
}


.figure {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #FFFF00;
    border-bottom: 12px solid #FFFFFF;
    border-top: 12px solid #FFFFFF;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 50px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    width: 50px;
}
```

**The CSS Changes:**

```
.border {
    border-right: 3px solid #FF0000;
    height: 98%;
    left: 24px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 1px;
    z-index: -1;
}

    .figure {
        background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #FFFF00;
        border-bottom: 12px solid #FFFFFF;
        border-top: 12px solid #FFFFFF;
        display: inline-block;
        height: 50px;
        margin-right: 10px;
        width: 50px;
    }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: +1 this will be looking nice if you post the relevant CSS.  Little difficult to identify what you have modified.

Answer (score 1):

```
.border{z-index: -1;} use this
```

And see link http://jsfiddle.net/bipin_kumar/w5TY9/2/

Answer (score 1):

```
.figure{
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background: yellow;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 10px;
    z-index:1;
    border:3px solid white;
}

.border{
  border-right: 3px solid red;
  height: 100%;
  left: 24px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 1px;
    z-index:-1;
}
```

replace your classes with mine, you will get both effects

Comment: [Agreed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20351032/add-vertical-line-between-the-vertical-divs/20351139#20351139)

Comment: @NathanLee your solution looks better

Answer (score 0):

```
.border{
  border-right: 3px solid red;
  height: 100%;
  left: 24px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 1px;
}
```

Class need to be added the following property and value

```
z-index: -1;
```

Answer (score 0):

In your css you need to add the following two rules for the .border class:

```
  z-index: -1;
  margin-left: -1px
```

The first line puts the line behind the boxes. So in the vertical space without boxes the line shows up.

One small improvement for centering the border perfectly under the boxes:

Your border is 3px width so the border should be moved at least 1px to the left in order to stay centered. With margin-left: -1px you get the correct result. If you want the border to be completely perfect centered you should either use a border with of 4px and a margin-left of -1px or a border with of 2px and a margin-left of 1px;

see http://jsfiddle.net/w5TY9/1/

Answer (score -1):

Add **`z-index=-1`** to **border** class.

check this [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/praveen_jegan/w5TY9/3/)

Comment: dont answer same answers

Comment: @Zword This is only answer can be suggested, can you try other solution.

Comment: also see ur post CSS : z-index `=` -1.

Answer (score -1):

What you want is very easy. The short version is like this:

```
     <div style="background-color:yellow; height:30px;width:30px;">&nbsp;</div>
       <div style="background-color:red; height:30px; width:5px; margin-left:10px;">&nbsp;</div>
```

In this way you have a square with background yellow and below that you have a red line 
with 5px width or whatever you want.